# jQuery UI Dialog (version 1.10.4) Open Only Once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am implementing jQuery UI (version 1.10.4) in my web page and I have a pretty simple code here. The problem is, I don't know why it **only opens once**. Anyone can shed some lights?

**main code:**

```
<button class="subscribe">Subscribe</button>

    <div id="login-form" title="Sign In"> 
                        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
                        <form>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#login-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Login": function() {
                    //php code

                 },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
            });


            $(".subscribe").button().click(function() {
                $("#login-form").dialog("open");
            });
});
```

Comment: You cannot directly combine JavaScript (it means also jQuery and so on) with php.

Comment: @Václav Ya I know that, for that part I am going to redirect to a php page. But now the main problem is the pop up only shows once.

Comment: I looked into code where I have used dialog. My dialog (with list of ) opens each time - but I don't use modal version. I guess it is in modal dialog, itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `allFields` is not defined. It throws an error. With the line:

```
allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
```

commented out, it works fine.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4Kdw/1/

I added `$('input').val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");` to the fiddle to clear the fields without throwing an error.